# jquery get id from url and post to page with dynamic id

Tags: php, jquery

I need to make a like/dislike section using jquery and html
so I have this code:

```
    $('#like').mousedown(function() {
       var name = $('#like').val();
       $.post('php/vote_movie.php', { like: name }, function(data) {
          $('#like_feedback').html(data);
       });
    });
```

all works well if I manually type the url like `vote_movie.php/movie_id=22` for example.
but I need the url to update itself because in php I use `$_GET['movie_id']` url for the vote page so jquery needs to take that id from url and match-it with `$_GET['movie_id']` from `vote_movie.php`

basically I need something like this:

```
$('#like').mousedown(function() {
   var name = $('#like').val();
   $.post('php/vote_movie.php?movie_id=<$_GET['movie_id']>', { like: name }, function(data) {
      $('#like_feedback').html(data);
   });
});
```

and I have no idea how to do it because I'm a newbie in both php and java.

Any help on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Update:
to a better understanding here are my files:
likes.js `http://pastebin.com/FnVFrDZX`
watch_movie.php `http://pastebin.com/QVScXZCd`
vote_movie.php `http://pastebin.com/g70xbvsf`

Comment: So you just want to get `movie_id` from your URL?

Comment: i'm confused now. ispin after my tail to much. so in like.js at the url, should be the watch_movie.php's id the problem is that i call like.js inside watch_movie.php wich  so like.js in a way should know the id of the page that it's calling it. is this possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert "data-id" to like button.

Example:

```
   <span class="likebutton" data-id="1234567" id="like"></span>

 $('#like').mousedown(function() {
       var name = $('#like').val();
       var dataid =  $('#like').data('id');

       $.post('php/vote_movie.php?id='+dataid+'', { like: name }, function(data) {
          $('#like_feedback').html(data);
       });
    });
```

Comment: `<img style="cursor:pointer; height: 16px;" src="img/liike.png" data-id="<?php echo $movie_id ?>" id="like" />`i still get 0 as ID and this is inside likes.js: `$('#like').mousedown(function() {
var name = $('#like').val();
var dataid =  $('#like').data('id');
$.post('vote_movie.php?movie_id='+dataid+'', { like: name }, function(data) {
$('#like_feedback').html(data);


});
});`

Comment: Use chrome browser and press F12 before click to like button. Now click like button and look at error.

Comment: and i want to ask you something. what is the "like: name" ? for what?

Comment: id of the pic/ wich triggers vote_movie and feedback

Comment: but image has not name value. how can you get it?

Comment: don't really understand this .. the jquery and button code i got them from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EHbBHm5l4g  but since i want 3 options for this vote, i didn't use the php code because it's very different of what i need.

Comment: if i can bind another property to the image in wich to get the movie_id and then call it inside the link in JS like the first example you gave me, i think it should work.

Comment: http://cinebot.tk/watch_movie.php?movie_id=9/X-Men-Days-of-Future-Past-2014-(HDRip-AC3-MiLLENiUM).html    click on like and see that it works except the fact that isn't inserting the right id in the data base. it's inserting 0 instead of 9

Answer (score -1):

after another many hours of searching and trial&error, i finally did it.

in my likes.js i added:
`var baseUrl = (window.location).href; // You can also use document.URL
var koopId = baseUrl.substring(baseUrl.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
$.post('vote_movie.php?movie_id='+koopId+'', { like: name }, function(data) {`

and in my vote_movie.php i added:
`$movie_id = $_GET['movie_id'];` INSIDE the if statement

`if (isset($_POST['like']) && $ip_down != $ip) {
$movie_id=$_GET['movie_id'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO like_movie(like_user_ip, like_like, like_movie_id) VALUES('" . $ip . "', '1', '" . $movie_id . "')") or die(mysql_error());`

thank you for answering and helping me to open my horizon in searching new methods.

Comment: sorry for late. i'm happy for your fix :)))

Comment: thanks :) actually it was because of your ideea with dataid that i managed to think of searching some more jquery functions :) that's why i accepted your answer ;)